# jquery is not rending first table tag

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui

I was going through the jquery `attr(key,func(){})` example 
[Jquery attr example](https://www.qctutorials.com/learning/jquery/codeit.html@qcode=attr-key-func) to apply border using `attr(key,func)` but it's not applying border for first table tag.

First i thought it was jquery libray/browser issue but it gives same result on different browsers and jquery versions

I also tried differrent versions of jQuery library but

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en-US">

<head>
  <title>An Example for testing | QcTutorials</title>
</head>


<head>
  <title>The Selecter Example</title>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="../../js/jquery.js">
  </script>

  <script type="text/javascript" language="javascript">
    $(document).ready(function() {

      $("table").attr("border", function(arr) {
        return arr;
      })

    });
  </script>
</head>

<body>


  <table>
    <tr>
      <td>This is first table</td>
    </tr>
  </table>

  <table>
    <tr>
      <td>This is second table</td>
    </tr>
  </table>

  <table>
    <tr>
      <td>This is third table</td>
    </tr>
  </table>

</body>


</html>
```

Comment: the border attribute only takes a 1 or 0 so try: `attr('border', 1)`

Comment: It will help if you learn some basic javascript debugging techniques.  In this case, add an `alert` (or `console.log` (F11)) inside the function:  `$("table").attr("border", function(arr) { alert(arr); }` and then try that directly, `$("table").attr("border", 0);` should show you the problem.

Answer (score 3):

Its rendering the attribute, its not visible as the value is `0`. IN[`.attr( attributeName, function )`](http://api.jquery.com/attr/#attr-attributeName-function) the first argument of the function is `index` so its setting `0` for first table. Then `1`, `2`.....

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("table").attr("border", function(index, value) {
    return index + 1;
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table>
  <tr>
    <td>This is first table</td>
  </tr>
</table>

<table>
  <tr>
    <td>This is second table</td>
  </tr>
</table>

<table>
  <tr>
    <td>This is third table</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```